# Recursively loop through a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, callback, es6-promise

I am getting a list of droplets from a DigitalOcean API, but the list of droplets are per page.

The response give you the list of droplets on the page and the next page...

I am trying to get the next page of each promise recursively:

```
getDropletsPerPage(command,firstPage).then((response)=>{

    nextPage= response['nextPage']
    droplets= response['droplets']
​
    getDropletsPerPage(command, nextPage).then((response)=>{

        nextPage= response['nextPage']
        droplets= response['droplets']
​
        getDropletsPerPage(command, nextPage).then((response)=>{

            nextPage= response['nextPage']
            droplets= response['droplets']

            // Repeat until last page..
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use recursion:

```js
const dispatcher = {
    page: firstPage,
    droplets: [],
    execute: function () {
        const self = this;
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            getDropletsPerPage(command, this.page).then(function (response) {
                self.page = response['nextPage'];
                self.droplets = self.droplets.concat(response['droplets']);
                if (nextPage === LAST_PAGE) {
                    resolve(true);/* done */
                } else {
                    self.execute().then(function () {
                        resolve(true);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
dispatcher.execute().then(function() {
    /* reached last page */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to collect droplets info from all the pages you can accumulate the data in an array that is passed as a argument to every subsequent call of the recursive function (until the last page is reached):

```
const getDroplets = (page, droplets = []) => {
  if (/* end of the pagination is reached */) {
    return Promise.resolve(droplets);
  }
  return getDropletsPerPage(command, page).then((response) => {
    return getDroplets(
      response.nextPage,
      droplets.concat(...response.droplets)
    );
  })
};

getDroplets(firstPage).then(droplets => {
  console.log(droplets);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it:

```
    async getDropletsList(command, dropletsList, currentPage) {
        if(!currentPage) return dropletsList // here you've to check if there is another valid page
        const { nextPage, droplets } = await getDropletsPerPage(command, currentPage)
        dropletsList = dropletsList.concat(droplets)
        return getDropletsList(command, dropletsList, nextPage) // recursive call
    }
```

I hope it helps you :D

Answer (score -1):

what about using a recursive function

> recursive function is a function that calls itself during its
>   execution

so your code will be like this

```
const recursion = async (command, firstPage) => {
  const { nextPage, droplets } = await getDropletsPerPage(command, firstPage)
  // do what ever you want 
  if (nextPage)
    await recursion(command, firstPage)
  else {
    // something else 
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to accumulate the droplets from each page. How would this give the OP the list of droplets on all pages?

Comment: by declaring a global variable and using it to store the result for each call?